YoutubeApi v3 - get videoId from activityId
Using YouTube's v3 activities.list API, is there a way to access videoId?
I can't seem to find a way to do it. Is it even possible?
I tried using YouTube's search api, but it costs 100 units, which makes it to costly to use.
Am I missing something here?
Thanks

The combinations of getting the snippet & contentDetails does the trick.
